# geom_text in ggplot - gem_bar - geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a factor called (AuftragsTyp). Each of my records has a factor level for this. So I want to make a gemo_bar plot out of it. It works fine.

```
ggplot(data=auftraege_gefiltert_kopf) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=AuftragsTyp)) +
  dark_theme_grey()
```

It counts all records with each factor level and the plot looks like this:
[image: Plot]

Now I would like to add the count of each level as text but nothing works.
I had something like this

```
geom_text(aes(label = "count"), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y

What is the right way to add the count as text to this plot?

And the same for this plot where I added a fill. I would like to have for each factor the count

```
ggplot(data=auftraege_kopf_positionen) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(y=Mitarbeiter, fill = Fakturiert)) +
  dark_theme_grey()
```

[image: plot2]

Thank you and cheers
Dominic

Comment: Try putting `aes(x=AuftragsTyp)` in the first `ggplot()` call

Comment: Use `after_stat(count)` maybe

Comment: Try `geom_text(aes(x=AuftragsTyp, label = ..count..), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), stat = "count")` to add the x aes, to compute the count via stat="count". and to map it on the label aes via label =..count.. or label=after_stat(count)